# LT8330 Boost Converter burst mode

Tags: dc-dc-converter, boost

I have a [LT8330 Boost converter](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2034975.pdf?_ga=2.190145635.974595544.1551781533-1044917867.1551175329) issue. As the output load decrease, this boost converter will use a burst mode, switching between sleep and activity, and thus decreasing the switching frequency.

[image: Burst frequency vs load current]

The output load at which the LT8330 reaches the fixed 2MHz frequency varies based on input voltage, output voltage, and inductor choice. **However, I can't figure out the relation between those parameters and how to predict the switching frequency based on those parameters.**

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DCDC converters I used to work on decided between PWM (Pulse Width Modulation and continuous switching) and PFM (Pulse Frequency Modulation or Burst mode) operation based on the **current** through the switch.

The LT8330 appears to do the same, see page 9 of the datasheet:

> While in Burst Mode operation the current limit of the
>   switch is approximately 240mA

From that I conclude that when the current through the switch exceeds 240 mA, the converter switches to PWM.

When the converter is in PWM, the switching frequency is 2 MHz, which is the frequency of the internal oscillator (meaning it will not be exactly 2 MHz).

When the converter is in PFM (pulsed mode) **when it switches** (during a burst) the switching frequency will be 2 MHz, same as in PWM. However, it depends on the load current, input and output voltage, inductor value etc. how **often** there needs to be a burst. When the load current is small (for example 10 uA) a burst might be needed only once per second (just my guess) but at 50 mA much more bursts are needed.

So it is nearly impossible to predict how often a burst is needed, the system monitors the output voltage and initiates a burst **when needed**.